# The WHERE clause error in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am creating a DB raw query, to return a record between two dates, but giving an error, my MYSQL look like this `2018-01-25` using the format Y-m-d

***This is my query***

```
public function index() {
        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
        $format = 'Y/m/d';
        $now = date($format);
        $to = date($format);
        $data = [
            'from' => $now,
            'to' => $to
        ];

        $em = $this->getEm($data);
        return view('report.index', ['em' => $em, 'search' => $data]);
    }


private function getData($data) {
        return DB::table('A')     
        ->select('A.firstname', 'A.middlename', 'A.lastname')
        ->where('date_hired', '>=', $data['from'])
        ->where('date_hired', '<=', $data['to'])
        ->get()
        ->map(function ($item, $key) {
        return (array) $item;
        })
        ->all();
    }
}
```

The following error occurs when I run the query

```
 (1/1) InvalidArgumentException
Illegal operator and value combination.
```

The question is how to remove the error to return results, who can assist me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Additional Where Clauses**

`whereBetween`

The whereBetween method verifies that a column's value is between two values:

```
public function index() {
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $format = 'Y/m/d';
    $now = date($format);
    $to = date($format);
    $data = [
        'from' => $now,
        'to' => $to
    ];

    $em = $this->getEm($data);
    return view('report.index', ['em' => $em, 'search' => $data]);
}


private function getData($data) {
    return DB::table('A')     
    ->select('A.firstname', 'A.middlename', 'A.lastname')
    ->whereBetween('date_hired', [$date['from'], $data['to']])
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($item, $key) {
    return (array) $item;
    })
    ->all();
}
```

Above code will help you.

Hope this will helps you!!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `whereBetween` [Query-Builder-Where-Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses)